# LEFT JOIN sql query not correctly executed in huge data in VBA

Tags: mysql, vba, excel

Please find my below SQL query code and table's which i am executing via VBA.

```
sql_string = "Select " & _
"[one_key$].[APRIL_2017] From [Sheet5$]" & _
 " LEFT JOIN [one_key$] On [Sheet5$].[ClientCode]=[one_key$].[Code]"
```

[image]

The query is correctly executing for 700-800 entry but when i am trying to execute the same on around 9k to 10k rows its not giving me proper result.

Please guide how can i instruct the above query to give exact match instead of random match.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [sql LEFT JOIN query is not working Properly in VBA Excel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47151175/sql-left-join-query-is-not-working-properly-in-vba-excel)

Comment: @AntiDrondert I found that when left join is execute the client code is sorted also by smaller to larger is is possible to keep it same..like main table.